About 'Suppose $Z_i$ are i.i.d. $N(0, 1).$ And let $M_n = \max\{Z_1, \ldots, Z_n\}$, show that $P(M_n > t) \leq n(1 - \Phi(t))$'
Re question of https://stats.stackexchange.com/users/395275/lisa-w
Suppose $Z_i$ are i.i.d. $N(0, 1).$ And let $M_n = \max\{Z_1, \ldots, Z_n\}$, show that $P(M_n > t) \leq n(1 - \Phi(t))$

I notice independence isn't used. I remember usually when you have $\max > t$ you usually change the probability to '1 minus' like $P(\max > t) = 1-P(\max \le t)$ and then use independence. Similar for $\min < t$. I was surprised that for a change I didn't see this.

https://stats.stackexchange.com/users/79698/jimb gives a hint 'A first step is showing $P(M_n > t)=1−(\Phi(t))^n$'

Well, I notice $1 - (\Phi(t))^n \le n(1-\Phi(t))$ is true because $1+x+x^2+...+x^{n-1} = \frac{1-x^n}{1-x} \le n$ because $1+x+x^2+...+x^{n-1} \le \sum_{i=1}^{n} 1 = n$ whenever $0 < x < 1$, i.e. whenever $x$ is a non-degenerate probability. Hence,


$$P(M_n > t)$$
$$= 1 - P(M_n \le t) \ \text{hooray for the 1 minus}$$
$$= 1 - P(Z_1, ..., Z_n \le t)$$
$$= 1 - P(\bigcap_{i=1}^{n} \{ Z_i \le t \})$$
$$= 1 - \prod_{i=1}^{n} P(\{ Z_i \le t \}) \ \text{by independence!}$$
$$= 1 - \prod_{i=1}^{n} \Phi(t) \ \text{by identical distribution}$$
$$= 1 - (\Phi(t))^n \le n(1-\Phi(t))$$
Question: Since there's clearly a shorter way, what's going on?
Guess: The instructor didn't realise there's a shorter way? Or maybe it's just to show another proof of $1 - (\Phi(t))^n \le n(1-\Phi(t))$, w/c we do by viewing $P(M_n > t)$ in 2 different ways?

The linked method uses a "union bound" which is barely one step beyond the axioms. It's good for new students to learn this bound, and it is useful because it is true regardless of the dependence structure! Your approach is exact but relies on independence and is a bit more advanced (barely, but still) for a new student.

Inequalities can be mysterious because--since they are not exact--they often can be proved with a wide array of approximations.  Different methods of approximation can provide different insights.

@knrumsey 1 - JimB was the 1 who brought it up. so it's superfluous? 2 - i mean at the very least is there simply 2 ways to prove things and that's it?  3 - And well what''s the point of independence?

@whuber 1 - simply 2 ways to prove things and that's it?  2 - And well what''s the point of independence? 3 - JimB was the 1 who brought it up. so it's superfluous?

@BCLC, I'm not sure what you mean by "what's the point of independence". Sometimes independence is a reasonable assumption, and other times it is not. IF you are willing to assume independence, the "long way" is a stronger result, because it is exact (and the inequality is just an implication of the stronger result). If the random variables are dependent, then this procedure is not valid, but the linked one is.

There are far more ways to prove this!  I do not understand your question "what's going on," nor do I get the point of your comment "that's it."

@knrumsey maybe it's like there are 2 exercises with the same assumptions 1st is inequality and then 2nd is equality and then the 2nd can prove the 1st but then you can also prove the 1st without the 2nd?

@whuber maybe it's like there are 2 exercises with the same assumptions 1st is inequality and then 2nd is equality and then the 2nd can prove the 1st but then you can also prove the 1st without the 2nd?
